# Popup warning control using python splinter

Tags: python, selenium, splinter

When I use the splinter python, popup warning appear. I want to click the button there but i can not control it (with the splinter). did any one know how to use it?

Comment: could you please provide your code and popup image then we will able to help. Thanks

Comment: You should start with doc: https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iframes-and-alerts.html